# How can I compare request.getParameter(string) in Controller class with MySQL database?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, html, spring

I'm currently working on a (relatively) basic web application that functions as a time clock for a fictional employer. Currently, the application implements HTML, JavaScript, Java, MySQL, the Spring Framework and xml. I have a log in page, and it takes the user input for the Username and Password and stores the information. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to take that information and compare it with the MYSQL database to successfully log in. I can post examples of code, if necessary and thanks in advance for the assistance.

This is a piece of the LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jsp/login")
public ModelAndView existUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ModelAndView("UserPrint.jsp", hashmap.makeHashMap());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "userLogin")
public ModelAndView loginUser(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) {
    String strLoginJsp = "login.jsp";
    String strSessionErrorAttribute = "errors";
    User sessionUser = getUserFromSession(session);

    if (request.getHeader("referer") == null
            || request.getHeader("referer").contains("AddNewUser.html")) {
        session.setAttribute(SESSION_USER_ATTRIBUTE, new User());
        session.setAttribute(strSessionErrorAttribute, "");
        return new ModelAndView(strLoginJsp, hashmap.makeHashMap());
    }

    User requestUser = new User();
    String requestedUserName = request.getParameter("userName");
    requestUser.setUserName(requestedUserName);
    String requestedPassword = request.getParameter("password");
    requestUser.setPassword(requestedPassword);
    session.setAttribute(strSessionErrorAttribute, "");

    // Check if username and password is in DB
    User loginUser = userDao.login(requestUser);

    if (loginUser == null) {
        // Either the username doesn't exist, or the password was bad.
        if (userDao.userNameExist(requestedUserName)) {
            // user entered bad password
            if (sessionUser.getUserName() != null
                    && sessionUser.getUserName().equals(
                            requestUser.getUserName())) {
            } else {
                sessionUser.setUserName(requestUser.getUserName());
            }

        }
    } else {// username does not exist in db
        session.setAttribute(strSessionErrorAttribute,
                "Please register account.");
```

Here's a piece of the UserDao:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("fetchAllUsers");
    return query.getResultList();
}

public User login(User user) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("userLogin");
    query.setParameter("userName", user.getUserName());
    query.setParameter("password", user.getPassword());

    List<User> currentUsers = query.getResultList();

    if (currentUsers.size() > 0) {
        return (User) currentUsers.get(0);
    }

    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public Boolean userNameExist(String userName) {
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("getUserWithUsername");
    query.setParameter("userName", userName);
    List<User> existUser = query.getResultList();

    if (existUser.size() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please, post some code.
What exactly is the issue?

On the most basic level you should be able to:

1. pass the username and password as parameters in the HttpServletRequest object
2. Retrieve said parameters by "name" from the HSR object in the Controller.
3. Pass them to the SQL query for comparison against the database field.

Which of the above steps failed?

Comment: Posted some code samples. To be honest, I'm still fairly new to all of this and I've been thrown in the proverbial deep end. I would say that number 3 is where I'm currently having issues. I have my SQL queries, and my hsr parameters, but I have no clue how to compare them.

Comment: Is this Hibernate? In your situation, I would recommend building this first using basic Java technologies, without frameworks and without ORM. Straight Java, Servlets, JDBC. Even if you are going to throw away this code, it will help you understand what the higher level technologies are using "under the hood", so if something goes wrong, it will be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would take your login and password and search for a user

```
String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='"+sanitize(userLogin)+"' AND password='"+sanitize(userPass)"'";
```

This is not actual code just psuedo code.  I do not know how java or spring handles sanitation but it is of utmost importance that you dont' trust anything input by the user when you are building a query string.

The idea is if this results in 1 user the user is valid, if it returns none the user is not valid!

Using paramaterized queries could be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

To expand on dm03514 's answer - yes you should "sanitize" user input by using prepared statement objects in Java JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring then you should use spring-security. They have pretty much done this for you already and you just have to configure it.